# Htmlspecialchars output when running a query

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel

I am creating an array of pages using the following query:

```
$pages = Page::orderBy('sorting')->get()->toArray();
```

When I then `json_encode` the output, the output is corrupted when one of the page titles has a quote in it. How can I prevent this?

Comment: json_encode handles strings that contain quotes and double quotes correctly. Could you paste an example of that "corrupted" JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return json, you should use:

```
$pages = Page::orderBy('sorting')->get()->toArray();
return response()->json(['pages' => $pages]);
```

it should not make any problems. In case you have any, please show what they are.

I've experienced problems with json only when I have DB connection non-UTF and have their some characters. As `json_encode` needs data be in UTF-8 it might cause problems

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is indeed returning a correct JSON. It seemed the javascript needed to call the object in a weird style, where the object needed to be placed within single quotes: `UINestable.init('{ $json) !!}')`. So when a single quote was within the JSON it would fault. Thanx though